# Adobe Air 20.0 breaks our OS X Native Extension and Captive Runtime not an option

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

Adobe dropped a lump of coal in our stockings in December with Air update 20.0. I'm certain that the 64-bit requirement is great for many, but we've been unable to get our ANE to work and have unhappy customers.

We've followed the suggestions for updating Flash Builder with the Air 20 SDK for eclipse and for the sdk.

We've built a 64-bit framework, built the ANE and incorporated the ANE into a project. I've dug out dtrace and watched the framework load, but have not been able to call anything in the framework since I don't believe its ever getting initialized.

Here's the symbol table from the framework:

```
                     U _FRENewObjectFromUTF8
0000000000001020 d __ZZ18contextInitializerE11functionMap
0000000000000f30 s __ZZ6say_hiE3msg
0000000000000ec0 T _contextFinalizer
0000000000000e80 T _contextInitializer
0000000000000f00 T _helloAneExtensionFinalizer
0000000000000ed0 T _helloAneExtensionInitializer
0000000000000f88 S _helloVersionNumber
0000000000000f60 S _helloVersionString
0000000000000e30 T _say_hi
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

I've completely dumbed down an ANE probject for OSX that you can find here: [leopoldodonnell/Air-20-64bit-ANE](https://github.com/leopoldodonnell/Air-20-64bit-ANE)

If you've got a similar project that works, I'd love to see it, if not, I'd appreciate someone showing me where we've gone wrong. It could be our framework though I can see the symbols as text using nm.

Comment: Have you tested any ane on ios or other platforms? I don't have any ane for OSX but my ios ones are fine.

Comment: Our App is Windows and OSX, so, no we haven't. I'm not 100% certain if there's an issue with how we've built our framework since its a C++ dylib and not Objective C, but its possible. Like I said, the symbol dump suggests things are cool.